# how to post text image into twitter same time in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i did one application here i need to share my score on twiter,i did using below code my score is posing fine,but now i need to share score along with app icon.but i dont know how to share that image along with text can any one help me,thankyou

```
    TestPost.class: 
public class TestPost extends Activity {
String review;
private TwitterApp mTwitter;

private String username = "";
private boolean postToTwitter = false;

private static final String twitter_consumer_key = "";
private static final String twitter_secret_key = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.post);

    Button postBtn              = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText reviewEdit   = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.revieew);

    postBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             review = reviewEdit.getText().toString();
            postToTwitter = true;



            onTwitterClick();

        }
    });

    mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, twitter_consumer_key,twitter_secret_key);

    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);



    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        username    = mTwitter.getUsername();
        username    = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;


    }
}



private void postToTwitter(final String review) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int what = 0;

            try {
                mTwitter.updateStatus(review);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                what = 1;
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what));
        }
    }.start();
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String text = (msg.what == 0) ? "Posted to Twitter" : "Post to Twitter failed";

        Toast.makeText(TestPost.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
private final TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String value) {
        username    = mTwitter.getUsername();
        username    = (username.equals("")) ? "No Name" : username;




        postToTwitter = true;
        postToTwitter(review);

        Toast.makeText(TestPost.this, "Connected to Twitter as " + username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String value) {


        Toast.makeText(TestPost.this, "Twitter connection failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
private void onTwitterClick() {
    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Delete current Twitter connection?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       mTwitter.resetAccessToken();


                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();


                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        alert.show();
    } else {


        mTwitter.authorize();
    }
}

   }
```

Comment: I think you can't share images or icons in twitter unless you share it as a separate link

Comment: ok,thnku.but i have to share both same time

Comment: add image to flickr and post the link to twitter post.

Comment: kindly check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758058/android-image-tweet/15760736#15760736

Comment: i checsd that app.here while taking pic from getting exception,and acutally i dnt want post gallry image,cam image directly along with score i have to share the app main icon every time

Answer (score 0):

This is how I upload an Image along with text to the logged in Twitter User's account. I make use of the [TwitPic API](http://dev.twitpic.com/) for that. You will have to login and register a developer account there.

The solution can be thought of as a two step solution.

First, when the user clicks the post button, I first grab the Image and upload to TwitPic. From there, I grab the URL that is returned by TwitPic (`String url = upload.upload(finalFile);`).

In step two of this code, in a String instance (`String finalStatusWithURL`), I grab the content of an `EditText` and then append the URL from step 1 to it. With this done, the post is finally posted to Twitter.

```
Configuration conf = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY)
.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
.setOAuthAccessToken(twit_access_token)
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twit_access_token_secret)
.setMediaProviderAPIKey(TWIT_PIC_API)
.build();

// SET THE FILE PATH
File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(initialURI));
// THIS IS IMPORTANT. TWITPIC NEEDS THE ACTUAL PATH ON THE DEVICE. JUST THE URI DOES NOT WORK!!!!

ImageUpload upload = new ImageUploadFactory(conf).getInstance(MediaProvider.TWITPIC);

String url = upload.upload(finalFile);
Log.e("TWITTER URL RESPONSE", url);

// NOW, UPLOAD TO TWITTER

ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(YOUR_TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);

AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(your_twit_access_token, your_twit_access_token_secret);
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build()).getInstance(accessToken);

String finalStatusWithURL = null;

if (finalStatusMessage.trim().length() > 0) {

    finalStatusMessage = editStatusUpdate.getText().toString();
    finalStatusWithURL = finalStatusMessage + ":\n " + url;

} else {
    finalStatusWithURL = url;
}

twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(finalStatusWithURL);
Log.e("TWITTER RESPONSE", response.getText());
```

This is a method to get the real path of the image you want to upload:

```
// HELPER METHOD TO GET REAL PATH FOR THE SELECTED IMAGE
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 
    cursor.moveToFirst(); 
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
    return cursor.getString(idx); 
}
```

Hope this helps. This is production code from an app of mine.

**UPDATED:**

Change this in the code:

```
File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(initialURI));
```

To this:

```
Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), icon);
File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
```

And the *helper* method for `Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bmpFinal);`:

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

You will still need to pass a Bitmap object. To convert your app icon to a Bitmap, use this:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

**UPDATED 2:**

A little while after you asking and me answering your question, Twitter wrapped up a developer meet in SF. They have introduced a few new *Cards* which I *think* may be of use to your specific use-case. It is fresh off the block and I haven't gotten around to testing/using it. But if it fits your purpose, take a look at these links:

1. http://www.engadget.com/2013/04/02/twitter-cards-apps-products-photo-galleries/ (Where I found out about the new feature)
2. https://dev.twitter.com/blog/mobile-app-deep-linking-and-new-cards (The official Twitter blog)
3. https://dev.twitter.com/cards (Developer page for details of the features and how to use them)

Comment: thnyou.but i dont want to select any image from gallery or camera just directly i need to add one icon.

Comment: ok.please see my code postToTwitter("welocme"); like that i am posting text beside welcome i have to post icon

Comment: @radha: Unfortunately, unlike Facebook, Twitter displays images differently. What you wish to achieve, in my opinion is not possible.

Comment: if suppose  i got 10 marks in game.am sharing that score in twitter"u got 10 marks"along with that msg beside i have to display app main icon image

Comment: @radha: Again, that is not how Twitter works. Sorry. Try using the default Twitter app or any twitter app and you will see just the behavior I mentioned in my earlier comment. Not how you want it to show.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27396/discussion-between-radha-and-siddharth-lele)